# MySQL Query issue match new row

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 2 tables

CustomersTable and
ChargesTable

Customers has 3 fields

Billing #, Company, Account #

Charges has 2

Company , Account #

I need to add a 3rd colum to ChargesTable with the correct billing # form the CustomersTable, that matches the company and account #.

Doest anyone know a efficient way to do this in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a column to your second table (assuming INTEGER column type):

```
ALTER TABLE ChargesTable ADD COLUMN BillingNumber INTEGER NULL;
```

Then update all the ChargesTable records by joining it with the first table:

```
UPDATE ChargesTable CH
JOIN CustomersTable CU ON (
      CH.CompanyNumber = CU.CompanyNumber
  AND CH.AccountNumber = CU.AccountNumber)
SET CH.BillingNumber = CU.BillingNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo-create statement, which if you execute will show you a basic relational structure (I think what you're after).

It demonstrates relational constraints, but is lacking a real design or structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
  `BillingNumber` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Company` VARCHAR(64) NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `Charges` (
  `BillingNumber` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Company` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  INDEX `fk_table1_Customers_idx` (`BillingNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_table1_Customers1_idx` (`AccountNumber` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_Customers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`BillingNumber`)
    REFERENCES `Customers` (`BillingNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_Customers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AccountNumber`)
    REFERENCES `Customers` (`AccountNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create the new field in the table Charges.
you need to update the values:

```
update charges c
join customers cu on cu.Company=c.Company and
cu.Account=c.Account
set c.NewBilling=cu.Billing;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2449/4